Streaming a response in Laravel?
Is it possible to keep an http connection open through Laravel such that the response can be streamed over time?
For example, when a user hits one of my API endpoints, it returns some data. But I'd like to keep the connection open and return more data over time.
Is this possible?

HTTP request? No. But you can do so with websockets instead.

Hi, yes you can use StreamedResponse Object in Laravel In order to achieve this. This enables one to send response in chunks.
